# How to read json data using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to read data from config file, but it always returns empty. Do you have any idea what is implemented wrong here? I have added typing.d.ts:

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

main.ts

```
 import {CFactory} from "./local";

const config =  './cacheConfig.json';

const fact = new CFactory();

const cache = fact.getObject();

cache.setConfig = config;
```

Comment: Is there somewhere you're pulling in the data? All you've done is assign a filename to a variable.

Comment: @jhpratt added code

Answer (score -1):

import json file in main.ts

```
import * as data from './json_filename.json';
```